# Social login with MAUI .net example

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I tried to find any sample about how can I implement social authentication with my project but I cannot find any, do someone have such sample, especially authentication with Facebook and Google

Comment: look at this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Actually I do not want to use Azure